# NSPersistentCloudKitContainer on a specific CKRecordZone

Tags: core-data, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I'm investigating the way to add a iCloud-sync functionality to a NSPersistentDocument based app.

Could I use `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` and use a different `CKRecordZone` for each document?
Each document would then sync to iCloud.

Note that using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` is a requirement.